# How to append log output of pg_dump backup command PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, logging, postgresql-9.4, pg-dump, pg-dumpall

I am using below command to append.

`pg_dump -Fc  -h hostname  -W  --dbname=dbanme -f dbname.sql --username  2>demo.log`

I want to log into demo.log like below sample output.

````
pg_dump: reading user-defined tables
pg_dump: reading packages variables
pg_dump: reading user-defined packages
pg_dump: reading user-defined synonyms
pg_dump: reading extensions
pg_dump: reading user-defined functions
pg_dump: reading user-defined types
pg_dump: finding typelem dependencies for user-defined types
pg_dump: reading procedural languages
pg_dump: reading user-defined aggregate functions
.
.
.
....```

If we run in mysql using --verbose it will log all stuff using below command.
``` mysqldump -u -p dbname --log-error=error.log --verbose >bkp.sql```
how we can achive in PostgreSQL?

Please help.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use --verbose as stated below

./pg_dump -Fc  -h hostname  -W  --dbname=dbanme -f dbname.sql --username postgres --verbose 2>demo.log